# Jenkins/ansible-vault bug?

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I'm using a Jenkins job with an ansible-playbook.
I have encrypted my private key from AWS EC2 with ansible-vault.
When I start my job in Jenkins, I have that key specified in the vault section. But when playbook tries to connect, it gets an error:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Load key \"/home/ubuntu/workspace/triggered_by_gitlab/ansible/ec2_key.pem\": invalid format\r\nubuntu@172.31.6.81: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
```

When I run this playbook with `--ask-vault-pass`, same error.

But when I decrypt it manually with `ansible-vault decrypt file_name`, and run ansible playbook from my ansible machine CLI, no error is raised.

Comment: I know is not a solution, but by experience please, don't launch ansible in Jenkins, use rundeck for example or awx (but I don't recomand this one currently, is very difficult to handle).

Comment: `ansible(-playbook)` can decrypt on the fly playbooks, vars, files (to copy of lookup), templates.... but not ssh private keys (which have to be available before ansible connects). In this case, you have to decrypt that key as you just did prior launching the playbook. Meanwhile this is not the best solution here since you can add that key as s credential inside Jenkins directly.

Comment: @YLR can you please give some more arguments to your assertions: don't launch in jenkins / awx difficult to handle ? Since I have around 300 teams/1000 users launching ansible scripts through Jenkins, once in a while to dozen times a day, I'm very interested to know what kind of problems I should expect to face. We also have an AWX install where we let some teams access the GUI and interact through the API and I don't have an avalanche of tickets so far. I don't have any experience with rundeck though so I might totally ignore I'm living in a very dangerous and overly complex world.

Comment: Yes aggreed with you ;). Arguments : * Jenkins is more a build tool than a deploy tool * If you can't build your project you can still deploy with the other tool * User can't make the diff between "I buidl" and "I deploy" i'm ok with the CI/CD concept but it's important to used (dev adm ops etc...) keep the difference between this steps because build and deploy are connected in pipeline but it must be necessary to have the choice to make one without the other. The ansible output it's really ugly in jenkins and the invetory/node concept available in ansible is not connected with jenkins design

Comment: This comment suport is not the best medium to arg this point of view. @Zeitounator, if you have awx, it's ok. Just AWX it's not really "open mind" with ansible project (if fore any reason you don't have inventories direcoty at the root project, it's hard to configure) and it's a bit difficult to have more than on ansible version. Rundeck it's more premissive for the directory arch in project, and it could run more tools than just ansible (if you need to handle some technical task out of ansible scope)

Comment: I'm happy with this. I totally disagree with your two last explanations that I still up-voted for their existence. I agree it's not a place for arguing but people passing by deserve a little more than a simple "don't use it / it's too hard".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222605/discussion-between-ylr-and-zeitounator).